# Javascript equivalent to Clojure's "reductions" or python's itertools.accumulate

Tags: javascript, python, clojure, functional-programming, reduce

Is there a JavaScript equivalent to Clojure's "reductions" function or Python's `itertools.accumulate`? In other words, given an array `[x_0, x_1, x_2 ... x_n-1]` and a function `f(prev, next)`, it would return an array of length `n` with values:

`[x_0, f(x_0, x_1), f(f(x_0, x_1), x_2)... f(f(f(...)), x_n)]`

I'm simulating the desired behavior below:

```
function accumsum(prev, next) {
    last = prev[prev.length - 1] || 0;
    prev.push(last + next);
    return prev;
}

var x = [1, 1, 1, 1];
var y = x.reduce(accumsum, []);
var z = y.reduce(accumsum, []);

console.log(x);
console.log(y);
console.log(z);
```

which displays:

```
[ 1, 1, 1, 1 ]
[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
[ 1, 3, 6, 10 ]
```

But I'm wondering if there is a way to write something simpler like

```
[1, 1, 1, 1].reductions(function(prev, next) {return prev + next;});
```

If not, is there a more idiomatic way to do this in JavaScript than what I wrote?

Comment: If you don't mind libraries, check out [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) it has a reduce function which should accomplish what you want to do

Comment: @jcern: This is not a straightforward reduce (and plain JS now has `reduce`, unless you have to support the unmentionables).

Comment: Again with the libraries, [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com) (disclosure: I'm an author) has [`scan`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#scan) and [`mapAccum`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#mapAccum), which work in this manner.

Comment: Thanks Scott, I played around with Clojure for just a couple weeks and ended up taking a big swig from the functional Kool-Aid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var a = [1, 1, 1, 1];
var c = 0;
a.map(function(x) { return c += x; })
// => [1, 2, 3, 4]

a.reduce(function(c, a) {
  c.push(c[c.length - 1] + a);
  return c;
}, [0]).slice(1);
// => [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I'd use the first one, personally.

EDIT:

> Is there a way of doing your first suggestion that doesn't require me to have a random global variable (c in this case) floating around? If I forgot to re-initialize c back to 0, the second time I wrote a.map(...) it would give the wrong answer.

Sure - you can encapsulate it.

```
function cumulativeReduce(fn, start, array) {
  var c = start;
  return array.map(function(x) {
    return (c = fn(c, x));
  });
}
cumulativeReduce(function(c, a) { return c + a; }, 0, [1, 1, 1, 1]);
// => [1, 2, 3, 4]
c
// => ReferenceError - no dangling global variables
```

Comment: Is there a way of doing your first suggestion that doesn't require me to have a random global variable (c in this case) floating around? If I forgot to re-initialize c back to 0, the second time I wrote a.map(...) it would give the wrong answer.

Comment: Thanks, accepted answer b/c the encapsulated version.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, if you're in a situation where you're using an older version of JavaScript, or don't have access to [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org).

It's not difficult to implement from scratch and has some educational value.

Here's one way to do it:

```
function reduce(a, fn, memo) {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    if ( typeof memo === 'undefined' && i === 0 ) memo = a[i];
    else memo = fn(memo, a[i]);
  }
  return memo;
}
```

Also, other higher order functions can be written in terms of reduce, e.g. "map", shown here:

```
function map(a, fn) {
  return reduce(a, function(memo, x) {
    return memo.concat(fn(a));
  }, []);
}
```

for reference the equivalent imperative (and faster) version of map would be:

```
function map2(a, fn) {
  var newA = [], i;
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    newA.push(fn(a[i]));
  }
  return newA;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a stateless version

```
function reductions(coll, reducer, init) {
  if (!coll.length) {
    return [init]
  }
  if (init === undefined) {
    return reductions(_.drop(coll, 1), reducer, _.first(coll))
  }
  return [init].concat(reductions(_.drop(coll, 1), reducer, reducer(init, _.first(coll))))
}
```